# Use .pfx certificate for invoke RESTFul API from Apache Tomcat 8

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, pfx

I need a help about a installation of .pfx certificate on tomcat 8.

I have already installed a .pfx certificate on jvm throught the creation of jks.
I have already added a certificate in cacert

keytool -import -alias 192.168.56.100 -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -trustcacerts -file C:\EBCM_Client_TEST.pfx

I have already deployed a war of my server on tomcat 8 and I have configured connector on port 8444:

When I try to call a HTTPS API from server to other server, in the log I receive this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have already configured a server.xml of tomcat installation

```
<Connector port="8444" 
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
maxThreads="150" 
minSpareThreads="25" 
maxSpareThreads="75" 
enableLookups="false" 
disableUploadTimeout="true" 
acceptCount="100" 
scheme="https" 
secure="true" 
SSLEnabled="true" 
clientAuth="true" 
sslProtocol="SSL/TLS" 
keystoreFile="C:/EBCM_Client_TEST.pfx" keystorePass="allianzebcm" keystoreType="PKCS12"/>
```

In java, for creating a custom SSL Context I'm using

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/clientcert.jk");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "allianzebcm");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");

//my certificate and password
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/EBCM_Client_TEST.pfx");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "allianzebcm");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
```

Do you know how to configure the certificate pfx on tomcat for HTTPS client authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the port on Connector of server.xml

Error config

```
<Connector  port="8444"
```

Correct config

```
<Connector  port="8443"
```

Now I'm able to invoke REST API with pfx certificate.
Thanks